# How to add authentication to a specific page in a dash application

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have a dash app with multiple pages.

```
.
├── adduser.py
├── app.py
├── apps/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── exome.py
│   ├── familial.py
│   ├── oncomine.py
│   ├── prenatal.py
│   ├── rapidexome.py
│   └── targeted.py
├── auth.py
├── data/
├── dataprocessor.py
├── index.py
├── layouts.py
└── static
    └── fileiconn.png
```

I just want to prompt the use for an admin password when they try to access the `/apps/exome` route. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes you could use dash basic auth https://dash.plotly.com/authentication. Might be a bit too basic depending on other requirements you may have or may have in the future, but can do what you ask in the question.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden i do know this but this is to secure the entire application. I just want to secure one route not the entire app. I know this is possible in flask and since dash is built upon flask i was wondering if it is possible in dash also

Comment: @HaziqSayyed after a search on the net I ended on your post. I am looking at a similar thing (ie "protecting" access to one tab). Did you manage to solve your issue? if so would you mind sharing what you did please?

Comment: @Hotone No i didn't find the solution i was looking for I ended up rebuilding the app with django and chart.js. Sorry for the late reply